# If I revoke current valid development certificate, then will it have expiry same as current certificate?

Tags: iphone, ios

If I revoke current valid development certificate, then will it have expiry date same as current certificate? Or it will have new expiry (which is of 1 year from date of creation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will have same date.
Revoking certificate is to be done after adding another device.
Contract is for only 1 year.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I am talking about Development certificate not provisioning profiles..... Certificate which is link with provisioning profile. That certificate will expire in 2 days, so not sure whether to wait till it expired for renew or revoke now?